# Dependency injection for ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Im working on a sample project where I need to create a GET method that saves the results in memory and not into a database.

Originally I created the dictionary in PersonController; however, that is a problem since it doesn't persist in memory after the GET request. I need to figure out how to only create one instance of NumbersByName and pass it into the Api Controller. Can this be done?

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<int>> NumbersByName;

    public PersonController(Dictionary<string, List<int>> numbersByName)
    {
        NumbersByName = numbersByName;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPersonsNumbers(string name)
    {
        var personsNumbers = NumbersByName[name];

        return Ok(personsNumbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: GET requests should not persist anything. GET requests should be idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use cache to store the data

Example:

```
public string[] GetNames()
{
  string[] names = null;
  if(Cache["names"] == null)
  {
    names = DB.GetNames();
    Cache["names"] = names;
  }
  else
  {
    names = Cache["names"];
  }
  return names;
}
```

You can apply the same concept in your code. You can take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397269/how-to-cache-data-in-memory-in-a-mvc-4-application)

Otherwise, you need to investigate using the singleton design pattern, that way you only create one instance.